# Extract password archive with double quote in windows command line

Tags: 7zip

I want to extract archive files (zip,rar,z7,gz,etc) from PHP. Because the passwords can contain special characters like ¡¿, and PHP exec does not support unicode characters (for some reason). I eneded up using a batch file as explained here [php exec() in unicode mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332321/php-exec-in-unicode-mode).

But, as lovely as windows 10 is, I can't seem to figure out how to extract an archive that has a single double quote as password...

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "C:\Users\me\Desktop\25mb.rar" -o"C:\Users\me\Desktop\" -p"password here" -y
```

That is the default line to extract using 7zip. *(note below)*
I have a file **25mb.bin** stored in **test.rar** stored in **25mb.rar** with password "  (single double quote).

The error is:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 13312 bytes (13 KiB)

Extracting archive: C:\Users\me\Desktop\25mb.rar
--
Path = C:\Users\me\Desktop\25mb.rar
Type = Rar
Physical Size = 13312
Solid = -
Blocks = 1
Multivolume = -
Volumes = 1

ERROR: Data Error in encrypted file. Wrong password? : test.rar

Sub items Errors: 1

Archives with Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 1
```

I tried:

```
-p" *
-p"" **
-p"""  *
-p"""" **
-p"^"" * (default escape for CMD)
-p"\"" *
```

*: *The line asks me if i want to overwrite, meaning that the -y is not executed but seen as part of the password.*

**: *Executes, but with error. The extracted file test.rar cannot be opened (is corrupted)*

*Note: This method has no problem whatsoever with ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]|:;'<>?,./€¡¿*

*Note: winRAR has a neat feature in which you can provide a file with a password, to use to extract, instead of providing a string. This however only works for RAR files(!) and is thus useless in my situation.*

Example with rar:

```
file_put_contents( 'C:\Users\bunny\Desktop\pass.txt', $password );
exec( '"C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\winrar" e -ad -p "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\25mb.rar" *.* "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\" < "C:\\Usersme\\Desktop\\pass.txt"', $extractStatus );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after testing random things, I managed to find the answear!

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "C:\Users\me\Desktop\dq.rar" -o"C:\Users\me\Desktop\" -sccutf-8 -y < C:\Users\me\Desktop\pass.txt
```

Note that the -p parameter is NOT present(!) (if added, it doesn't work)

The file pass.txt contains "\r\n  (double quote followed by a line break)

The "-sccutf-8" option ensures that special characters work as well!

It works!

**Edit 2:**
When the password file contains special characters like °, ¡, ¿ or §, this method still works! You do have to set "-sccutf-8" in order to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this answer helped me well. I used this in my Powershell script on my Win10 notebook:

(First a user puts password to $input_txt)

```
$input_txt | Out-File ".\pw.txt" -Encoding default
cmd /c ".\7za.exe" e ".\myfile.zip" -o".\" -sccWIN -y `< ".\pw.txt"
```

And escape "<" as Powershell can understand this using backquote.