# Extract archive with password that contain double quote

Tags: windows, powershell, 7zip

i want to extract an archive called test.rar with 7zip but nothing worked for me
Archive: test.rar
Password(with quote):"."
I tried

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" t  -p'"".""' test.rar 
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" t -p""."" test.rar
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" t "-p"."" test.rar
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" t -p'"."' test.rar
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" t -'p"."' test.rar
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" t -p'"".""' test.rar
```

Comment: How about extracting the archive manually with the GUI this time and using another password without double quotes next time?  ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract password archive with double quote in windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438074/extract-password-archive-with-double-quote-in-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to at least PowerShell 7.1, passing arguments with embedded `"` characters to external programs such as `7z.exe` is [fundamentally broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375), unfortunately.

While there are workarounds, the simpler solution is to provide the password *via stdin*.

The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438074/extract-password-archive-with-double-quote-in-windows-command-line) that [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen) links to shows this technique for `cmd.exe`, via `<`, its input-redirection operator, which PowerShell does *not* support, however.

Instead, use PowerShell's *pipeline* to supply data that an external program receives via stdin.

Assuming that the *verbatim* password is `"."`:

```sh
'"."' | & "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" t test.rar
```